# Fire event when user scroll reach an anchor-element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to fire event when user manually scrolls to an anchor element? Actually detecting the anchor and not using distance from top.

Comment: Is there a problem with using distance from the top? It would be the normal way of achieving this functionality.

Comment: I used this: https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear. It still checks distance from top but it's so much more easier to use if you are familiar with jquery.

Comment: @GaryThomas I guess not. I was mostly curious. It seems a bit unnecessarily complicated. But really I don't understand the workings of the browser so I should just be quite...